# SQL Server 2008 R2: starting SQL browser failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

During troubleshooting of the failed connection to sqldb in my testsystem I've tried to start sqlbrowser via command line. This results the following error message "failed starting SSRP redirection services -- shutting down". Does anybody have an idea how this problem could be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be caused by an old version of SQL Server 2000 that was improperly removed.

In summary, SQL Browser is a replacement for the SSRP redirection service. If you no longer have SQL 2000 on your computer, check the registry for a key named "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion". If it is there, rename it to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion_old". There may be an additional, similar key at "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432\Microsoft\MSSQLSERVER", so you should check there too.  Once you have changed the registry, see if you can start the SQL Browser service.

See [this MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/09/18/sql-browser-service-is-not-running-on-server.aspx) for details.